# Combining Two Tables & Summing REV amts by Mth

Tags: sql, t-sql

### Below are my two tables of data

```
Acct BillingDate  REV

101  01/05/2018    5

101  01/30/2018    4

102  01/15/2018    2

103  01/4/2018     3

103  02/05/2018    2

106  03/06/2018    5

Acct BillingDate Lease_Rev

101  01/15/2018    2

102  01/16/2018    1

103  01/19/2018    2

104  02/05/2018    3

105  04/02/2018    1
```

### Desired Output

```
Acct  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr

101    11   

102    3

103    5    2

104         3

105                    1

106              5
```

### My SQL Script is Below:

```
SELECT   [NewSalesHistory].[Region]
                    ,[NewSalesHistory].[Account]
                   ,SUM(case when [NewSalesHistory].[billingdate] between '6/1/2016' and '6/30/2016' then REV else 0 end ) + [X].[Jun-16]  AS 'Jun-16'
    FROM [NewSalesHistory]
    FULL join    (SELECT      [Account]
                     ,SUM(case when [BWLease].[billingdate] between '6/1/2016' and '6/30/2016' then Lease_REV else 0 end ) as 'Jun-16'
    FROM [AirgasPricing].[dbo].[BWLease]
      GROUP BY [Account]) X ON [NewSalesHistory].[Account] = [X].[Account]

    GROUP BY [NewSalesHistory].[Region]
                ,[NewSalesHistory].[Account]
    ,[X].[Jun-16]
```

I am having trouble combining these tables. If there is a rev amt and lease rev amt then it will combine (sum) for that account. If there is not a lease rev amt (which is the majority of the time), it brings back NULLs for all other rev amts accounts in Table 1. Table one can have duplicate accounts with different Rev, while the Table two is one unique account only w Lease rev. The output above is how I would like to see the data.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify: are you trying to pull just the most recent revision from table 1?

Comment: Pull from both Tables.

Comment: Let me clarify.  Are you trying to pull all data from table 1 or just the top 1 (i.e. most recent revision)?

Comment: I need to pull all data from table 1 and all data from table 2 (which has the lease_rev information)

Comment: @JVeenk You post 4 to 5 versions of the same question, but none of them are answered because no one understand what you want.  Learn how to ask question before posting another question.  Read this link carefully.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `union all` and `group by`:

```
select acct,
       sum(case when billingdate >= '2016-01-01' and billingdate < '2016-02-01' then rev end) as rev_201601,
       sum(case when billingdate >= '2016-02-01' and billingdate < '2016-03-01' then rev end) as rev_201602,
       . . .
from ((select nsh.acct, nsh.billingdate, nsh.rev
       from NewSalesHistory 
      ) union all
      (select bl.acct, bl.billingdate, bl.rev
       from AirgasPricing..BWLease bl 
      )
     ) x
group by acct;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the rest of the columns in the database are different for each Table. Table 1 has like 40 columns and table 2 has 4 columns so I don't think Union all will work.

Comment: Union all will work with narrow select statements.  After all, you're not doing a union on the whole tables, just what you select form them.

Comment: One table has the rev labeled as newbillingdata and the other table rev column is labeled extprice.

Comment: This is just a small sample from the big picture.  I have 20 other columns from table 1 for all the text information I need.  Wouldn;t know how to incorporate the other columns from a union all .

Comment: @JVeenk I'm sorry, rev is revision or revenue?  Also, you're free to name the columns anything you want.  So    select newbillingdata as xxx ...

Comment: @JVeenk . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  If you have another question, ask it as *another* question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there are a few things going on here:

1) As Gordon Linoff mentioned you can perform a union all on the two tables.  Be sure to limit your column selections and name your columns appropriately:

```
select 
     x as consistentname1,
     y as consistentname2,
     z as consistentname3
from [NewSalesHistory]
union all
select 
     a as consistentname1,
     b as consistentname2,
     c as consistentname3
from [BWLease]
```

2) Your desired result contains a pivoted month column.  Generate a column with your desired granularity on the result of the union in step one. F.ex. months:

```
concat(datepart(yy, Date_),'-',datename(mm,Date_)) as yyyyM
```

Then perform aggregation using a group by:

```
select sum(...) as desiredcolumnname
...
group by PK1, PK2, yyyyM
```

Finally, PIVOT to obtain your result: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

3) If you have other fields/columns that you wish to present then you first need to determine whether they are measures (can be aggregated) or are dimensions.  That may be best addressed in a follow up question after you've achieved what you set out for in this part.

Hope it helps

*As an aside, it seems like you are preparing data for reporting.  Performing these transformations can be facilitated using a GUI such as MS Power Query.  As long as your end goal is not data manipulation in the DB itself, you do not need to resort to raw sql.*